# Please check the confirmation dialog on your device

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I am trying to connect adb device and it showing **"Please check the confirmation dialog on your device"** ..but there is no adb confirmation(rssi) dialog.

Same adb setup for other device. I checked with https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086501/2624806 and some other post as well. But it's not working for me.

Any suggestion!

Comment: disconnect the phone; adb kill-server; adb start-server; make sure the phone is at the home(launcher) screen unlocked; reconnect the phone

Comment: Did you find the answer ?

Comment: It's long time..but as far as I remember I have to perform reset device and then command to kill and start adb server.

Comment: reset device??? It's my main phone...

Comment: hmm...since I was testing on Developer device :| .

Comment: in my case this instruction worked. https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html & if you have android studio 3.3+ then go to tools -> connection assistant. follow that instruction in end it will show confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 25):

This usually happens when you miss accepting the RSA Key Notification at first.
Best would be to reset the setting.

Do as follows:

1. Switch OFF `Developer's option`.
2. Under Developer Setting, Tap on `Revoke USB Authorization`
   [image: Hello]
3. Switch ON Developer's option
4. `Enable USB Debugging`, and you would see RSA Key Notification on device

   [image]

   You should immediately see the above notifiaction.
5. Select `Always allow from this computer` and Ok.
   To avoid further denial.

The link mentioned in your question should also work.
Might be some issue.

**Update:**
This might also be an Issue with your `adb` binary version.
Check `adb` version using:

```
$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
```

If you are using an older version please update.

Comment: and here it not showing me this dialog...any othe suggestion?

Comment: You mean Step 4. What is the output of `adb devices` ?, `unauthorized` ?

Comment: I am able to reproduce the issue, and above step work fine. Maybe you can try restarting the device, plug-unplug and Restart ADB process.       You basically need the Step 4 Notification to be accepted.

Comment: it's latest one Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31

Comment: Not working for me .. i have latest adb version 1.0.32

Comment: Not working for me on OnePlus6 A6000 OxygenOS 9.0.7 Android Version 9.  I only get the notification USB debugging connected.   adb Version 1:8.1.0+r23-5~18.04

Comment: There is no Revoking option at all in USB menu.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I have two different Linuxsystems on my computer.
The installation on MX-Linux 19.3 xfce was very easy and working after a short time.
The installation on Mint 19.3 Cinnamon would not work.
All instructions i found in google didn't solve my problem.
After deleting the files adbkey and adbkey.pub in my directory, i didn´t get these files, when i followed the instructions. I got always the status "device unauthorized" and did not get the  "confirmation dialog on my device".
Then i had a divine inspiration. In a console i gave me root permission via su
and started there droidcam. I imediately got the confirmation dialog on my smartphone and the driodcam was working fine. The files adbkey and adbkey.pub are now in the directory  /root/.android.

Answer (score 0):

For me, selecting the **Revoke USB debugging authorizations** would crash the entire Settings app. Here's a simple method that worked for me (I had root access to the device):

> The method is to simply copy your machine's `adbkey.pub` from the `~/.android/` directory, and put it into the Android device's sdcard (using Web or MTP) named as `adb_keys`, then copy the file into the correct path:
>
> ```
> # On the problematic device
> cp /sdcard/adbkey.pub /data/misc/adb/adb_keys
> ```
>
> (Note: there's a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42052776/1454514) on SO that goes into further details for this method.)

I have explained a bit more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58585698/1454514), if anyone's interested.

Answer (score 0):

For me, simply toggling the `USB Debugging` option when the device is plugged in got the dialog to show for me.