# Set adb vendor keys

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, att

EDIT: I figured out the problem, i think. ADB found out I wasn't on the latest updates (at&t released a stagefright udpate and i didnt know) so ADB didn't let me debug. Everything is fine now.

I have been debugging my app on an AT&T HTC One M8 for about a month. Suddenly today when I plugged in my phone, I didn't get the authorization popup. After an hour of troubleshooting, I found the problem, but not a solution.

This is the error i get in Android Studio 1.3.1:

> device unauthorized.
>   This adbd's `$ADB_VENDOR_KEYS` is not set; try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
>   Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.

I googled `$ADB_VENDOR_KEYS` but to no avail.

Information:

- Phone: AT&T HTC One M8 running 5.0.1 (API 21)
- Android Studio version 1.3.1 build 141.2135290
- JDK Version: 1.8.0_60

How can I get the popup again? I need to debug my app

Comment: Try going into dev options on your device and clearing the access list.

Comment: Orthogonal to the issue, albeit, perhaps the following documentation resource may serve to be of any help, as to explain a meaning of the `ADB_VENDOR_KEYS` environment variable for its applications: _[Secure USB debugging in Android 4.2.2](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2013/02/secure-usb-debugging-in-android-422.html)_, by Nikolay Elenkov

Answer (score 69):

In this case what you can do is :
Go in developer options on the device
Uncheck "USB Debugging" then check it again
A confirmation box should then appear

Answer (score 33):

I tried almost anything but no help...

Every time was just this

```
➜  ~ adb devices    
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
aeef5e4e    unauthorized
```

However, I've managed to connect my device!

This is the step-by-step tutorial.

1. Remove existing adb keys on PC:

```
$ rm -v .android/adbkey .android/adbkey.pub
```

2. Remove existing authorized adb keys on device, the path is `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys`
3. Now create a new adb keypair

```
    adb I 47453 711886 adb_auth_host.cpp:220] generate_key '.android/adbkey'
    adb I 47453 711886 adb_auth_host.cpp:173] Writing public key to '.android/adbkey.pub'
```

4. Manually copy from PC `.android/adbkey.pub` (public key) to Device on path `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys`
5. Reboot the device and check `adb devices` :

```
➜  ~ adb devices
List of devices attached
aeef5e4e    device
```

Permissions of `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys` are `(766/-rwxrw-rw-)` on my device

Comment: how can i "Remove existing authorized adb keys on device" on device which is still unauthorized by adb ?

Comment: @BourdierJonathan using terminal app on device, or using "Revoke USB debugging authorization" menu entry under Developer Options

Comment: @BourdierJonathan try to reboot in recovery and make those manipulations  with phone being in recovery mode

Comment: using `scp`/`ssh` is also an option for copying `chmod`ing files (in case you can install SSHelper or anything similar)

Comment: This is the most reliable solution, you might have to run 'adb shell' as root.

Comment: Just a note, if you want to add multiple PC as authorized to a single device, just append the public keys to `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys`

Comment: [Harald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7761292) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66080503) saying "...After this procedure it didn't work at first. But an additional `adb kill-server` helped.Thanks ColCh...you saved my day and possible more in the future."

Answer (score 6):

look at this url  [Android adb devices unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638582/android-adb-devices-unauthorized) else briefly do the following:

1. look for adbkey with not extension in the platform-tools/.android and delete this file
2. look at `C:\Users\*username*\.android`) and delete adbkey
3. `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.android` and delete adbkey

You may find it in one of the directories above. Or just search adbkey in the Parent folders above then locate and delete.

Comment: I figured out the problem. ADB found out that I wasn't on the latest updates ( I didn't know AT&T released the stagefright update) so it didn't let me debug

Answer (score 6):

If you have an AVD, this might help.

Open the **AVD Manager** from Android Studio. Choose the dropdown in the right most of your device row. Then do **Wipe Data**. Restart your virtual device, and ADB will work.

Answer (score 4):

I tried every method listed here and in [Android adb devices unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638582/android-adb-devices-unauthorized)

What eventually worked for me was the option just below USB Debugging 'Revoke auths'

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem running Ubuntu 18.04. I tried multiple solutions but my device (OnePlus 5T) was always unauthorized.

**Solution**

1. Configure udev rules on Ubuntu. To do this, just follow the official documentation:
   https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device

   The idVendor of my device (OnePlus) is not listed. To get it, just connect your device and use `lsusb`:

   `Bus 003 Device 008: ID 2a70:4ee7`

   In this example, `2a70` is the idVendor.
2. Remove existing adb keys on Ubuntu:

   `rm -v ~/.android/adbkey* ~/.android/adbkey ~/.android/adbkey.pub`
3. 'Revoke USB debugging authorizations' on your device configuration (developer options).
4. Finally, restart the adb server to create a new key:

   `sudo adb kill-server
    sudo adb devices`

After that, I got the authorization prompt on my device and I authorized it.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you just need to recreate new device