# Google Glass - Error while Installing APK

Tags: android-studio, google-glass, android-studio-2.1

I'm trying to use Android Studio 2.1.2 to develop an app over the summer for the Google Glass. At first AS wouldn't even recognize the device and I did the whole disabling the driver signature enforcement and changing the android_winusb.inf file and AS now recognizes the glass but when I try to run my project it comes up with this:

> com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device unauthorized.
>   This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
>   Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
>   Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
>   Error while Installing APK

and none of the fixes online are working. What do I do? Windows 8.1, debug is enabled on glass

Answer (score 1):

Try these following workarounds:

- Try revoking the permissions on the device. `Developer options` -> `Revoke USB debugging authorizations`. Then plug the device in and accept it again.
- Set your `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` again. `Unplug device` -> `adb kill-server` -> `adb start-server` -> `plug device`

Check these related links:

- [Android Studio - ADB Error - "...device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079838/android-studio-adb-error-device-unauthorized-please-check-the-confirmat)
- [Android adb devices unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638582/android-adb-devices-unauthorized)
- [Set adb vendor keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132434/set-adb-vendor-keys)