# IMAC does not recognize my Galaxy S4

Tags: android, android-studio

Has anyone had similar problem. I am trying to launch app using my Galaxy 
S4 but Android Studio doesn't recognize it.

Comment: What OS? Is debugging turned on? Can other apps access it? What did you try?

Comment: Ok, When I try to launch it recognizes the phone but under compatibility android studio says. Compatible =NO Minsdk API15 deviceSdk API 1

Comment: My Galaxy S4's sdkAPI level show 1 in android studio, WHY! how can I change that .

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I get when I try to launch. Please have a look the in the image attached.

[image]

Comment: Did you get a dialog asking you if you want to accept this devices RSA key fingerprint? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968542/please-check-the-confirmation-dialog-on-your-device