# This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set

Tags: android

I uninstall my old android studio and delete folders from the previous installation. Then, I install the new version of android studio. But, I am having the same issue as the one on [Android adb devices unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638582/android-adb-devices-unauthorized)

Basically, the phone will not display a message which asked me to confirm.

I found the adbkey.pub and adbkey under C:/Users/$Name/.android are missing. Did anyone know how to regenerate them?

Thanks,

Answer (score 30):

1. Delete the folder "C:/Users/$Name/.android"
2. Restart the adb server (`adb kill-server; adb start-server`)
3. Next time you use adb to access the device, a popup will appear on device asking to allow to connect to adb server

Comment: Which folder?  That could stand clarification.  The only paths I see mentioned are from Windows, I'm under Linux.  I eventually got an authorization popup on the phone, that seems to have gotten me past the error

Comment: ~/.android is the folder you need to delete

Comment: Please note also need to restart your adb server (or your computer) after deleting the folder (adb kill-server; adb start-server)

Comment: I didn't restart the computer, but looked into taskmanager for adb.exe and kill that process. after which the message to allow usb debugging on this host is shown again and it worked again.

Comment: rm -rf ~/.android

Answer (score -7):

All you need to do is install Samsung USB Drivers for Windows.

Here's the link : http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows

Comment: It is not a samsung phone. Are you sure it will work?