# Cannot locate connected device in Processing

Tags: android, processing

I'm having trouble getting [Processing](https://processing.org/) 3.3.6 (x64) for **Windows 10** **to recognize my LG V20 android device**.

At first, I was getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` when I tried to run a sketch, and the Android SDK updater had 2 suggested updates that I couldn't install due to more errors. My phone was not listed in Processing. The device was I've enabled USB debugging, and the connection works; I can transfer files fine.

After reading across the internet with little advice or success, I tried uninstalling all Android-related files on my computer, as well as any Processing-related files. I uninstalled Java, JRE and JDK. I then reinstalled them all:

- Java 8u161 JDK and JRE
- Processing 3.3.6
- Android SDK (auto-installed by Processing)

It all installed without complaint, and everything seemed fine. However, Processing still can't find or recognize my device. I've also tried these exact steps on my laptop which has a mostly **clean install of Windows 10** (apart from chrome and some bloatware) with the same results.

I also tried running something via Processing's emulator; I may have done this wrong, but this comes up with a "Lost connection with emulator while launching" error.

From this, it feels like it HAS to be an issue with the phone, since it's on multiple PCs. But it also HAS to be an issue with the PC, since it occurs on both a phone and an emulator. Frankly, I'm dumbfounded as to what the problem is.

I'm not really sure what else I can do or try; I haven't found my problem anywhere else, and tried the solutions to all similar problems with no success. Does anybody have any ideas?

> **EDIT**: **I fixed the problem**. I tracked down the location of my adb.exe, and ran "adb devices" in cmd at that location. It listed one
>   device (mine), and said it was unauthorized. A prompt appeared on my
>   phone, and upon confirming it, the device was authorized.

Comment: you mean your phone is not connected with your android studio ?

Comment: @MohammadAli No, I'm not using android studio. I'm using Processing, which has a built in mode for Android if you install the SDK. However, it is having trouble running the sketches.

Comment: If you run `adb devices` from command prompt are you able to see your device?

Comment: @shadowsheep
USB Debugging is definitely enabled.

When I run adb devices, it finds one: "LGH(a bunch of numbers/letters) unauthorized"

Comment: @Vedvart1 if you have usb debug enable on your device that is not enough in order to debug on it. The device still have to trust your PC. Usually you get a popup message asking you if you wanna trust the new debugging platform. Try this: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144507/cant-authorise-android-device-in-usb-debugging-mode

Comment: @Vedvart1 and that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213954/how-to-solve-adb-device-unauthorized-in-android-adb-host-device

Comment: @Vedvart1 I see now your edit. That’s what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

first off all check is your device connected to sdk by running this command

```
sdk/platform-tools/adb devices
```

if your device name not found make sure that you have USB debug enabled

goto settings/developer settings/ allow USB debug mode

if you don't see this option search how to enable developer settings for your phone mine was like 
goto settings/about/software info 
and tap constantly on build-number for 7 times

Comment: USB Debugging is definitely enabled.

When I run adb devices, it finds one: "LGH(a bunch of numbers/letters) unauthorized"

Answer (score -1):

I love Processing and I dreamed with the chance to use it for making Android apps, as the "Android Mode" promises. Both mentioned issues (no device connection + no emulator available) as well as the endless red Java error messages couldn't never be fixed. I tried everything regarding Android Studio & SDK parameters & component installation, as well as different PC plattforms without success. Trying to configure the SDK for matching Processing's requirements was also a waste of time. Nothing helped. People who got it, they neither know how it runs nor why it doesn't.

Forget Processing for Android, use & enjoy programming with MIT App Inventor, and really start running apps in one hour. Let's use Processing for its original purposes.

Comment: Hi @alejandro-sincich and welcome to StackOverflow. It would be great if you could update your answer to address the question more directly, include platform details and versions etc. Also, even if there are other alternatives for development on Android it is always best to try and solve the problem in the way the author is trying to except if they ask for alternatives in the first place. Oftentimes a complete change of tech-stack is not an option for many questions.