# I can't create virtual device through android studio, nor configure my phone with adb

Tags: windows, flutter, android-studio, adb, android-virtual-device

Error Creating AVD
An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details.

I use windows 11, latest version available today. I don't use android studio to program, I use VSCode and program with flutter, I haven't used this PC for a while, and now besides not being able to create an AVD (virtualization is enabled in the bios), I can't connect my cell phone to send it to it, this it returns to me in the terminal when I try to connect by wifi:

```
{path}\Sdk\platform-tools> ./adb pair 191.52.129.80:43883
Enter pairing code: 485667
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status length): connection reset
When I connect by usb cable, it returns me this:
! Device RX8N207HSZK is not authorized.
       You might need to check your device for an authorization dialog.
```

Since I already authorized everything and on my other computer it works.

```
Java version:
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
java 17 2021-09-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17+35-LTS-2724)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-LTS-2724, mixed mode, sharing)
Flutter version:
Flutter 2.10.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7e9793dee1 (31 hours ago) • 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
Engine • revision bd539267b4
Tools • Dart 2.16.1 • DevTools 2.9.2
```

Below I will leave all flutter doctor information with the -v parameter:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.22000.493], locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 2.10.3 at C:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 7e9793dee1 (31 hours ago), 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
    • Engine revision bd539267b4
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[✗] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    ✗ Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20

[✓] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.36.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64 • Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.22000.493]
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 99.0.4844.51
    • Edge (web) • edge • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 98.0.1108.62
    ! Device RX8N207HSZK is not authorized.
      You might need to check your device for an authorization dialog.

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

In short: I'm desperate for a solution, I've already tried deleting android studio from the locations I knew ('user/{user_name}/Android', 'AppData/local/Android' and 'AppData/roaming/Google/AndroidStudio') as well as android studio folder in program files and reinstall it, I tried to reinstall flutter and java and also nothing, I hope I don't need to format my machine :'(

Comment: Have you unlocked your device and checked for the authorization dialog as the error message suggests?

Comment: Yes, I even thought it could be the cell phone, but I tested it on another pc and it worked normally. Only on this pc that I can't run.

Comment: Delete the RSA authorization key files on the PC in `~/.android` and try again. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226666/android-adb-key-not-working/226669#226669 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213954/how-to-solve-adb-device-unauthorized-in-android-adb-host-device/56952514

Comment: I had already deleted these files, I noticed that the .android folder only had the 'studio' folder inside, so I'm copying this folder from another working computer to my pc. Any significant changes update here

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem in a bizarre way. I copied the '.android' folder from another working computer and pasted it into this one and it worked.